# Should I use browser or ptor = protractor.getInstance()?

Tags: angularjs, automated-tests, protractor, end-to-end

I watched this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idb6hOxlyb8) which was uploaded Aug 2013. It claims that we should use

`ptor.get(url)`

rather than

`browser().navigateTo(url)`

in future. But when I look at docs on the protractor home page (on git hub) and their newest examples are still using browser.

I am wondering if any one knows the movement to use

`var ptor = protractor.getInstance()`

still happening?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Using `ptor` is [obsolete](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0120), you should switch to `browser` from now on.

Regarding the modern way to navigate to a page, use: `browser.get(url)`

If is not an angular page then `browser.driver.get(url)`

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your reply. Could you please give a reference to say that is obsolete? (It does look that way, I just would like to have a confirmation. Thank you! =) )

Comment: [reference in protractor changelog.md](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0120)
'browser is an instance of protractor. This was previously accessed using protractor.getInstance.'

Comment: Thanks @nilsK for providing the reference! I updated the answer with it :)

Comment: [reference to browser](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser) in Protractor API docs