# Accessing synchronous behavior via a Protractor instance

Tags: testing, jasmine, protractor

I would like to inject a protractor instance into my tests, and then use this to perform navigation and element selection, but it appears that the functionality hanging off the `Protractor` object is all asynchronous, and the functionality on `browser` and `element` is synchronous.

Is there a way to access the synchronous behavior via the `Protractor` object?

Also: I have seen tests that invoke the following at the start:

```
protractor.getInstance()
```

...and I have seen tests that use the globally available `browser` and `element` objects directly.

What are the important differences between these two approaches?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25496379/3049002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in protractor is synchronous. It just looks that way before jasmine has been patched (by jasminewd) to wait for the async code so that it's easier to work with.

Please read https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs to see how controlflow makes everything in webdriver look synchronous. Then read https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md to see how protractor did it with jasminewd.

The link shared by @glepretre (stackoverflow.com/q/25496379/3049002) tells you the difference between ptor.get and browser.get. In short, use browser.get()